# How to store the value of each element of pandas data frame in redis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, redis

I am writing a program that will read a data frame from csv file, then calculate the hash values for one of the attributes(columns) and store it as a new attribute at the data frame.  All of that is working fine.  However, what I want is to store the hash attribute as my key and the original attribute as its value in redis.  And I would like to do that to for each element in the specified columns in the data frame.  For example:

This is my original data frame :

```
  customer     value
     a           1
     b           2
     c           3
```

Then I want to calculate the hash for the value attribute:

```
  customer     value      hash
     a           1        23344
     b           2        34567 
     c           3        78987
```

Finally I want to store the hash attribute as my key in Redis and value as my value, so for example if I ask to get

```
 r.get(23344)
```

the expected answer will be:
          '1'

or :

```
> r.get('78987')
> '3'
```

Below is my python code, I reached to the part of r.set, my problem is that it is saving the whole attribute under the attribute name, so I am not able to query for a single element.

```
import hashlib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
df= pd.read_csv ('file.csv') 
df['hash']=df['value'].apply(hash) 

r.set(df['hash'],df['value'])
```

I apologize for the long explanation and I hope to get some hints as I am new to work with pandas and redis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `r.set(df['hash'],df['value'])` is not you want to do, redis set only accept a key-value pair as the pararmeter, such like `r.set(df[hash][0], df['value'][0])`.

So your code should be like below

```
for i in range(len(df['value'])):
    r.set(df['hash'][i], df['value'][i])
```

And this will work. Also you can use the redis pipeline to speed up this operation.

```
pipe = r.pipeline()
for i in range(len(df['value'])):
    pipe.set(df['hash'][i], df['value'][i])
results = pipe.execute()
```

Comment: try to make sure whether df['hash'] or df[hash] in your case